# Write Test class for custom controller having wrapper class that makes a HTTP callout

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, json, httpcalloutmock

Hello All Can anyone please help me to write test class for my custom controller.

Below is my custom Controller.

```
public class InsertDataInToNewShopCtrl{ 

    public InsertDataInToNewShopCtrl(){
    }  

    Map<String,Id> testMap = new Map<String,Id>(); 
    Map<Id,Shop_New__c> shopObjs = null;

    public PageReference GoToInse() {

        try{  
            HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
            Http http = new Http();
            req.setMethod('GET');

            String url = 'http://iprocureafrica.co/index.php/restApi/shop_c/3';
            req.setEndpoint(url);

            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            String json =  res.getBody().replace('\n','');

            parseJSON(json);   

            shopObjs = new Map<Id,Shop_New__c>([Select id,Shop_ID__c from Shop_New__c where Shop_ID__c IN : shopIds]);
            for (ID idKey : shopObjs.keyset()) 
            {
                Shop_New__c objShop = shopObjs.get(idKey);
                testMap.put(objShop.Shop_ID__c, idKey);
            }
            mapShopFields();
        }  
        catch(Exception e ){  
            Apexpages.addMessages(e);  
        } 

        return null;
    }



    public List<WrapperClass> wrappers{get;set;}

    Public String size{get;set;}  
    list<string> shopIds = new list<string>();


    public void mapShopFields(){
        List<Shop_New__c> shopRecords = new List<Shop_New__c>();  // object list

                    for(WrapperClass wc:wrappers)
                    {
                    Shop_New__c shp = new Shop_New__c ();   // object instance with memory allocation.
                    // field mapping
                        if(testMap.containsKey(wc.id)){
                            shp.Id = testMap.get(wc.id);
                        }
                    shp.Shop_ID__c= wc.id;
                    shp.Name = wc.name;
                    shp.Email__c = wc.email ;
                    shp.Supplier_ID__c = wc.supplierid;
                   // shp.User_Name__c = wc.username;
                    //shp.Password__c = wc.password ;

                   // shp.Pin__c = wc.pin;
                    //shp.Location__c = wc.location ; 
                    //shp.Telephone__c = wc.telephone ;


                    //shp.Gender__c = wc.gender ;

                    //shp.Type__c = wc.type ;
                   // shp.Last_Login__c = wc.lastLogin ;
                   // shp.Create_Time__c = wc.createtime ;
                    //shp.Salesforce_Status__c = wc.salesforcestatus ;
                    shopRecords.add(shp); // add to list
                    //List<Shop_New__c> spList = [select id from Shop_New__c limit 2000]

                    }

                    If(shopRecords .size() > 0 ) // check list size
                    {

                        upsert shopRecords ; // insert list.

                    }

    }

    public void parseJSON(String jsonstr){  
        if (jsonstr != null){  
        wrappers= new List<WrapperClass>();     
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonstr);  
        while (parser.nextToken() != null)  
        {  
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY)  
            {  

                while (parser.nextToken() !=  JSONToken.END_ARRAY)  
                {  
                    if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT)  
                    {  

                        WrapperClass ci = new WrapperClass();  
                        while (parser.nextToken() !=  JSONToken.END_OBJECT)  
                        {  


                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'id'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken();      
                                    ci.id = parser.getText();
                                    shopIds.add(ci.id);
                                }  
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'Name'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken();  
                                    ci.Name = parser.getText();
                                }  
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'Username'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.Username = parser.getText();  
                                }  
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'Password'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.Password = parser.getText();  
                                }  
                                 if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'supplierid'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.supplierid = parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'pin'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.pin = parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'location'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.location = parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'telephone'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.telephone = parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'email'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                   ci.email = parser.getText();
                                  // ci.email =  'test@gmail.com';
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'gender'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.gender = parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'type'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.type = parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'lastLogin'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.lastLogin= parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'createtime'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.createtime = parser.getText();  
                                } 
                                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText().tolowercase() == 'salesforcestatus'))  
                                {  
                                    parser.nextToken()     ;  
                                    ci.salesforcestatus = parser.getText();  
                                }
                        }  
                        wrappers.add(ci);  




                            }  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
      }     
    }  

    public class WrapperClass{  
        public string id {get;set;}  
        public string name {get;set;}  
        public string username{get;set;}  
        public string password{get;set;} 
        public string supplierid {get;set;} 
        public string pin{get;set;} 
        public string location{get;set;} 
        public string telephone{get;set;} 
        public string email{get;set;} 
        public string gender{get;set;} 
        public string type{get;set;} 
        public string lastLogin{get;set;}
        public string createtime{get;set;} 
        public string salesforcestatus{get;set;} 
        public WrapperClass(){  

        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm) outlines what you need to do. I suggest you work on the test and only post a question here is you get stuck and all Googling and asking your colleagues fails to provide an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to Mock the HTTP response. The official Apex documentation has plenty of examples doing that. A good starting point is [Testing HTTP Callouts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm) .

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I note that a lot of lines of code in your controller are related to parsing the JSON. If the field names of your WrapperClass match the names in the JSON (casing doesn't matter when deserializing), you can parse the JSON in one line using [JSON.deserialize](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize):

```
private void parseJSON(String jsonstr){  
    if (jsonstr != null) {  
        wrappers = (List<WrapperClass>) JSON.deserialize(jsonstr, List<WrapperClass>.class);
    } else {
        wrappers = new List<WrapperClass>(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: No not only parsing i am doing. I am inserting that json data in to salesforce object.

Comment: @NayanaPawar Sure, it is only the parseJSON method I'm saying can be made a lot shorter.

Comment: Please see mapShopFields() method also.

Comment: @NayanaPawar Yes I saw that method. Changing parseJSON will not impact it.

Comment: private void parseJSON(String jsonstr){  
    if (jsonstr != null) {  
        wrappers = (List<WrapperClass>) JSON.deserialize(jsonstr, List<WrapperClass>.class);
    } else {
        wrappers = new List<WrapperClass>(); 
    }
} That's it. But it gives me error.

Comment: @NayanaPawar OK, don't make the change right now as your aim is to write tests for this. But in general this approach works, and come back to it sometime and debug the problem.